# Scheme Calculator Negative numbers

Tags: racket

Could you help me with an example function code take an array of integers and gives the output of the array for negative numbers
thanks in advance
the user will enter this

> (sumNeg  '(3 -5 -2 b -5 1 b))
>   and  will get the solution -12

Comment: `'(3 -5 -2 ...)` is a list, not an array.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The idiomatic solution in Racket would be to use built-in higher-order procedures - notice that first you have to [`filter`](http://docs.racket-lang.org/reference/pairs.html#%28def._%28%28lib._racket%2Fprivate%2Flist..rkt%29._filter%29%29) the negative numbers from the *list* (it's not an array!) and then add them, and this is precisely expressed by the following procedure:

```
(define (sumNeg lst)
  (apply +
         (filter (λ (x) (and (number? x) (negative? x))) lst)))
```

To avoid a double iteration, we can use [`foldl`](http://docs.racket-lang.org/reference/pairs.html#%28def._%28%28lib._racket%2Fprivate%2Flist..rkt%29._foldl%29%29):

```
(define (sumNeg lst)
  (foldl (λ (x sum)
           (if (and (number? x) (negative? x))
               (+ x sum)
               sum))
         0
         lst))
```

Or even more idiomatic, we can use Racket's [Iterations and Comprehensions](http://docs.racket-lang.org/reference/for.html):

```
(define (sumNeg lst)
  (for/sum ([x lst]
            #:when (and (number? x)
                        (negative? x)))
    x))
```

Anyway, it works as expected:

```
(sumNeg '(3 -5 -2 b -5 1 b))
=> -12
```